# javascript: getElementById is not finding element

Tags: javascript, html

Explain to my why this works when I click the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
      document.getElementById('cover-img').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```

While this does not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    document.getElementById('cover-img').style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

It returns the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: The second one is running when the page loads, and so you probably have the script up in the `<head>`, which is before the element exists. Move your script to just before the `</body>`, and it should work.

Comment: Probably because cover-img doesn't exist at the time when you execute the script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3):

you can do that with pure css

```
@media(max-width:75em){
    #mydiv{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, just a workaround. Doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript

Comment: @AndrewL: the solution css is more interesting then JavaScript in this case.

Comment: That's subjective @IlyasMimouni Good answer regardless though.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples to better explain it:

In this example the JS is at the top so is ran before I make the div with the ID cover-img. Meaning when it is ran the getElementById returns 0 results, giving the error `Cannot read property 'style' of null"`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('cover-img').style.display = 'none';
</script>
<div id="cover-img">I'm still alive!</div>
<div>I'll be here not matter what...</div>
```

In this example however I've moved the script to after the cover-img div is created meaning getElementById has a result that can be passed to style.

And as you'll see the div is hidden.

```html
<div id="cover-img">I'm still alive!</div>
<div>I'll be here not matter what...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('cover-img').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

I hope that makes sense, I took the size bit out just to make it clearer but the same holds true with that in place.

That being said using CSS to achieve this is a much better solution as @Foker points out in another answer on this page.